Azure Devops pipeline not running Playwright test, driver not found
I have a set of Playwright API tests in a .NET 8.0 project. I want to run these tests on a Windows agent.
After downloading the artifacts from the build stage (on an ubuntu-latest) and extracting these files, I install Node and Playwright and display the workspace.
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
      command: 'ci'
      workingDir: 'MyApp'
- script: |
      npm install playwright 
      npx playwright install
  env:
      PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSERS_PATH: "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.playwright"
  displayName: 'Install Playwright'
- script: dir "$(Pipeline.Workspace)" /s
  displayName: 'Inspect Pipeline Workspace for Playwright'

Then the tests are started as follows:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Dotnet test'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: my-subscription-devops-sp
    scriptType: pscore
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'dotnet test $(Pipeline.Workspace)/out/MyApp.dll --no-build --logger trx'

The test fails with the following error message:

Driver not found: e:\AZDO\R1_work.playwright\node\win32_x64\node.exe

This directory is not present in the workspace, but I do find this directory:
e:\AZDO\R1\_work\296\out\.playwright\node\linux-x64\node

Strange this presence of the linux-x64 directory on a Windows platform.
I have tried everything, including cleaning the Playwright directory before the installation step and specifying that it is a Windows installation when installing Node, but that has not helped.

This path e:\AZDO\R1\_work\296\out\.playwright\node\linux-x64\node is more likely a path to a release pipeline. Did you use to run dotnet test in a release pipeline? Besides, what if you ran dotnet test xxxx/out/MyApp.dll on that agent machine?

It is indeed a release agent where the test has to run, same is done for Selenium tests without problems. In your suggestion to run dotnet test xxxx/out/MyApp.dll with what has xxxx to be replaced?

The path to your artifacts MyApp.dll

MyApp.dll is on this path: e:\AZDO\R1_work\296\out\MyApp.dll and this dll is found, so the only difference I see in your suggestion is running without --no-build --logger trx is that what you want me to try?

So you may test to run dotnet test e:\AZDO\R1_work\296\out\MyApp.dll --no-build --logger trx on that agent machine for a further investigation.

I implemented your suggestion and re-ran the tests and now it works fine indeed. Many thanks for this. What I do wonder is whether this is a stable solution, I think the number in the path (workdirectory ID) can change, causing the dll to still not be found.

I also suspected if the path e:\AZDO\R1_work\296\out\MyApp.dll was the working directory of your current build pipeline. It looks more likely the path of a release pipeline. Was your problematic pipeline a release pipeline or a build pipeline? Can you create a new build pipeline with the required steps to reproduce the issue? Please also verify the workspace path by running a script tree $(Pipeline.Workspace) /f /a and locate the path to your MyApp.dll; then you can run dotnet test MyApp.dll -no-build --logger trx command` in that path for a further test.

So I checked the tree and run the pipeline again with: dotnet test $(Pipeline.Workspace)/out/MyApp.dll so excatly the same as I did before opening this issue without changing anything else and now the tests runs without a problem. The pipeline is a Yaml pipeline with a quality scan stage, a build stage and a test stage where the artifacts from the build stage are downloaded and extracted, node and playwright are installed and the tests are running. This all is done on a release agent of the company.

I believe the current pipeline definition itself should work since you could run the same command manually. There could be other changes that were not shared. Have those runs been picking up the same agent machine? We may lack the information to reproduce the issue.

I have an idea why the same dotnet test command worked fine today but not last Thursday. A colleague of mine had the same problem in his pipeline and discovered that node.exe was in the directory e:\AZDO\R1_work_tool\node\ while it is expected to be in e:\AZDO\R1_work\ .playwright\node\ he then copied the directories to the right place with a script in his pipeline, which I have now benefited from. The question then is why nod.exe is not installed correctly.

That makes sense and appreciate your time to share the update. Would you briefly share the solution/script from your side which may help other community members with similar concerns. Many thx again.
